# Treshold signature computing

Tags: cryptography, multisignature, encryption

I have two questions:

1. Can someone point me to some solution providing multi-party **{t,n}**-threshold ECDSA?
2. I imagine that such scehemes works first by creating an ECDSA private key then sharding it to **n** subkeys, **t** of which subkeys are required to generate the initial ECDSA private key. Am I right?

I would appreciate any feedback on this topic as I am trying to wrap my head around such systems.

Thank you!